# Max of date, based on different column

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, max, dax

i'd like to identify the most recent date of one column, grouped by other column.[image]

i want to  identify my bigger "Valuation date" based on "Policy Effective Date", and if is possible assign 1 if is the most recent date, and 0 if not, i couldn't group by dates ,
this is my formula now:

```
_z_ValDate = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(vwLossRunData[ValuationDate]),
    ALLEXCEPT(vwLossRunData,vwLossRunData[EffectiveDate])
)
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a column:

```
_z_ValDate  = 
var curDate = vwLossRunData[Policy Effective Date]
return CALCULATE(MAX(vwLossRunData[Valuation date]), FILTER(vwLossRunData, curDate = vwLossRunData[Policy Effective Date]))
```

It takes the max of the [Valuation Date] from the filtered table by [Policy Effective Date]

Comment: is not affected by other filters, i mean, is doing over whole data, is there any way to do but only with current data (After filters)?

Comment: Why would you be concerned about this as this is pre calculated?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below Measure-

```
_z_ValDate = 

VAR current_row_pe_date = MIN(vwLossRunData[Policy Effective Date])

VAR max_v_date = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(vwLossRunData[ValuationDate]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(vwLossRunData),
        vwLossRunData[Policy Effective Date] = current_row_pe_date
    )
)

RETURN IF(current_row_pe_date = max_v_date, 1 0)
```